# SVG font-face with pyQt

Tags: python, qt, svg, pyqt5, qt5

I try to load the custom font in SVG and render it with python qt driver - PyQt.

I know that Qt supports **only** the static features of SVG 1.2 Tiny. 
(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html)

If you follow the link on qt site - https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/feature/1.2/#SVG-static, then you can find fonts and examples of use. I am trying to download a font from documentation, but Qt continues to render the form on the scene with the default font.

Tried to generate with next XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" viewBox="0 0 110 70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <font-face font-family="larabie-anglepoise">
            <font-face-src>
                <font-face-uri xlink:href="file:///{data[font_path]}#la"/>
            </font-face-src>
        </font-face>
    </defs>
    <rect x="00" y="00" width="110" height="70" stroke="#777" fill="none"/>
    <text x="00" y="70" font-family="larabie-anglepoise" font-size="50" stroke="#533"
        stroke-width="1.6">SVG</text>
</svg>
```

I can see next preview in PyCharm (if I change the path to a static string of course):

[image: correct path]

And if I change path (make incorrect xlink:href):

[image]

So as you see this is not a problem with a path to font.

And my question - is it possible to render SVG with legal XML font-face (w/o css selector)?

P.s. To a logical question - why am I doing this crap?.. I can give a very concise answer, I need to render both the Latin and the Cyrillic in the form but as far as I know, there are no monospace system and multi-platform fonts for my case.

Comment: Two questions. 1. If I understand correctly, the problem is that using format for XML (instead of an hardcoded string), the font is not loaded; if that's the case, are you sure that the output of the formatted string is correct? 2. Do you load the svg from a written file or dynamically, and do you follow the same procedure in both cases (format and hardcoded font path)?

Comment: @musicamante, Yeap. I am absolutely sure that the format is correct. I tried to hardcode the path to the font (SVG with the font) and insert it dynamically, the result is the same - the fonts do not work.

Thanks for answer.